# How to make "loop" patern with zeroes behind the numbers i get from String?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to ask something, i already get the number from string and put it inside string using replaceAll like this:

```
String y = "9.86-A5.321";
String x = y.replaceAll("\\D+","");
textview.setText(x);
```

Now my question is i need to make the number i get inside my String x (9865321) into something like this:

```
9865321
9000000
800000
60000
5000
300
20
1
```

How do i make it in Android Studio with Java?

Comment: What is the logic you are looking for? Take the first digit, and pad the number with zeros to the right until it is that many digits long?

Answer (score 2):

This is not tested, but the concept can be something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<digits.length; i++){
     StringBuild zeros = new StringBuild(digits[i]);
     String digitsTemp = digits.substring(i);
     for(int j=1; j<digitsTemp.length; j++)
     {
          zeros.append("0");
     }
}
```

The concept is iterate over your digit string, create a new string that will be the digit you want + 0's and create a copy of original digits, starting from the digit you want and onward.

Comment: is digits mean the x String?

Comment: If it's still relevant, I'm not sure what you asked here? digits is the string the user inputted 9249809 for example

Answer (score 1):

You have the length of the original number string, so you can iterate over every character of that string and add as many zeros to it as the difference between the string length and which position the character occupies in it:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      String string = "9865321";
      String string2= "";
      System.out.println(string);
      for (int i = 0; i< string.length(); i++) {
          string2 = Character.toString(string.charAt(i));
          for (int j = string.length()-1; j > i ; j--) {
              string2 = string2+"0";
          }
          System.out.println(string2);
      }
    }
}
```

This is the trivial way to do it. You should use a `StringBuilder` for `string2` instead, and you can probably optimize the two loops somehow, but the above code produces the correct output:

```
9865321
9000000
800000
60000
5000
300
20
1
```

Comment: how do i implemet this straight in button onclicklistener?

Comment: The listener will have a method that is executed when a particular event that the listener is listening for occurs. Simply put the relevant part of the code inside that method.

Comment: can you edited it in main activity and the same name as mine? cuz i just tried i just get "1" as result

Comment: I can't. I am not an Android developer and I don't have your code (you didn't share any code about activities, etc). That said, it is literally impossible that, for the input you provided, my code produces "1" as output. Feel free, however, to edit your question to share all the necessary code and we can take a look at what's going on with it.

Comment: ah okay, i see, i will edited my question soon

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper System.out.println() method won't actually do anything when doing coding in android studio. This will surely work in java but you cannot print anything in android like that...

Comment: @UtkarshSahu As I said I'm not an Android developer. The question in its original form is basically synonymous with "How to pad a string with zeros" and has nothing to do with Android